# slow down for-loop to count from 15 to 5 in 10 seconds

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart

I try to delay the output for my for-loop and print a count down a value once a second.
This is what I'm trying to do, but somehow it doesn't works.

```
  void main() {
  
  var actualCurrent = 5; //Value from DB later
  var delayedCurrent = 15; // Value gets set in programm
  
      for (int i=delayedCurrent; i > actualCurrent; i--) {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
                
                 print('value: '+delayedCurrent.toString());
                 delayedCurrent --;
               });
    
        }
}
```

If I put `i--` into `Future.delayed` the programm crashes.

What is to do to count from 15 to 5 in 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're running `main` on Future, that's why we need to make this function `async` to `await`.

[on dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1268d66f851a9151472a5485c959e57c&null_safety=true)

```
void main() async {
  var actualCurrent = 5; //Value from DB later
  var delayedCurrent = 15; // Value gets set in programm

  for (int i = delayedCurrent; i > actualCurrent; i--) {
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('value: ' + delayedCurrent.toString());
      delayedCurrent--;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> just add async and await for the delayed method. this will work.

```
void main() async{
  
  var actualCurrent = 5; //Value from DB later
  var delayedCurrent = 15; // Value gets set in programm
  
      for (int i=delayedCurrent; i > actualCurrent; i--) {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1),(){
                
                 print('value: '+delayedCurrent.toString());
                 delayedCurrent --;
               });
    
        }
}
```